# Update node and node modules to the latest version

Tags: node.js, module, upgrade, updates, node-modules

I have a node setup - v0.10.26 [Latest available version: v0.12.7]
And I have some 15 node modules, which I would like to update to the latest version.

On running, `npm outdated` and `npm outdated -g`, I got the list of modules/packages - their current version and the latest version available.
Documentation here: [npm outdated](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/outdated)

So how do I go about this?
Should I first update my node?
And then update the modules?

Before updating node, I just tried this command `npm update`
Documentation here: [npm update](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/update)

On the terminal, I could see it updating the modules.
But once the process was complete, I couldn't run `npm` commands anymore.
It's giving me this error:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'are-we-there-yet'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
```

Don't know what went wrong. Or what I did wrong.

Please guide me through the steps to update my node and node modules to the latest version.

Also after updating them, will my app run properly again?

Answer (score 1):

You can use nvm to manage Node versions, check out my post on that one: http://mycodesmells.com/post/node-version-management/

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I used the solution proposed in paragraph 1. of [this post](http://www.hostingadvice.com/how-to/update-node-js-latest-version/)

1. `> curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.32.1/install.sh | bash`
2. `> nvm install 6.9.5`